# Haskell - Recursive descent parser

Tags: haskell, recursive-descent

Can some one recommend a simple working example(code) of using recursive descent parser on haskell?
All the information I found are too difficult to understand. Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a chapter in, ["Real World Haskell"](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) devoted to `Parsec`, the recursive descent parser combinator library that comes with the Haskell Platform.  There's also a bunch of `Parsec` links on the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec).  Ultimately, once you get comfortable with the examples, you'll need the [reference guide](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html).

Answer (score 1):

While not especially simple, Robert Giegerich's script for his lecture "Programmiersprachen und ihre Übersetzer" is a literate program featuring a recursive descent parser for (IIRC) a minimal Pascal with excellent documentation. In German, though, and not available on the net, but you can [ask him directly](http://www.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/~robert/).